# Probability of a survivor

Tags: probability, random-graphs

In a room stand n armed and angry people. At each chime of a clock, everyone simultaneously spins around and shoots a random other person. The persons shot fall dead and the survivors spin and shoot again at the next chime. Eventually, either everyone is dead or there is a single survivor. As n grows, what is the limiting probability that there will be a survivor?

I have been trying to solve this problem for a while but couldn't find a good approach. Any insight is appreciated! Here are the probabilites for the small values of $n$:

$n = 2$ -> $0$

$n = 3$ -> $3 / 4$

$n = 4$ -> $48/81$

For much larger values of n, I ran some computer simulation and found that the answer gets close to $1 / 2$.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I would recommend writing this problem down using less of a story, and more mathematics.

Comment: For $n = 2$, clearly the answer is 0. For ${n = 3}$, answer turns out to be ${3/4}$. For ${n = 4}$, the answer is ${48/81}$. For much larger $n$ I ran some simulations and found that the answer converges to $1/2$.

I tried some recursive reasoning, but it quickly became intractable.

Comment: Thanks for the context! You should put that into the original post, since comments are prone to deletion.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2430193/group-russian-roulette?rq=1

Comment: Thanks @Manlio, that looks like the exact same problem :D

Comment: It doesn't converge to $1/2$.  Since the behavior for large $n$ is that about $n/e$ survivors remain after a single round, the probability is actually oscillatory, repeating about every factor of $e$.  Starting with $n=3$, my simulations with $10^6$ trials each give these probabilities: $[0.750553, 0.591565, 0.468419, 0.416254, 0.438881, 0.488488, 0.532949, 0.554202, 0.556286, 0.544488, 0.525525, 0.504147, 0.486463, 0.472484, 0.464400, 0.462105, 0.463823, \ldots]$.  It's oscillating between $0.54$ and $0.46$ or so.

Comment: [Here's](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.03805.pdf) the paper linked in the other question.